# How do I zoom on cursor position in mandelbrot or julia set?

Tags: c, math, fractals

I am writing a fractal explorer at the moment and I got stuck at zooming on a certain point in the set. My drawing function for the Julia set for example looks like this:

```
void *julia_thread(void *param)
{
    int x, y, temp;
    long double re, aux, im;
    int start = ((int *)param)[0];
    int end = ((int *)param)[1];
    int iterations;


    for (x = start; x < end; x++)
        for (y = 0; y < WIN_SIZE; y++)
        {
            re = range_change(zoom_factor, x, mv_x);
            im = range_change(zoom_factor, y, mv_y);
            iterations = 0;
            while (!blowing_up(re, im) && iterations < max_iter)
            {
                aux = re;
                re = re * re - im * im + re_c;
                im = 2 * aux * im + im_c;
                iterations++;
            }
            put_pixel(img, x, y, color_table[iterations]);
        }
    return NULL;
}
```

The function that calculates the initial values for the real and imaginary part of Z is this:

```
long double range_change(long double zoom_factor, int value, long double mv)
{
    long double newmax = 2 / zoom_factor;
    long double newmin = -2 / zoom_factor;

    return ((long double)value * (newmax - newmin)) / WIN_SIZE + newmin + mv;
}
```

So I get a scaled down value that is part of the interval where the fractal exists and according to the number of iterations I assign a colour to that certain pixel. Zooming works fine by making the real interval (-2, 2) smaller by dividing both of the ends with a factor. This works but I can't seem to be figure out how to zoom on a certain spot other than the centre. I can move around and reach that spot eventually by adding to the real and imaginary part (x, y) a number but I can't zoom on a point determined by the screen (x, y) given to me by the cursor position.

Comment: Where and how do you set the `((int *)param)` values? Those give you the starting and ending values for `x`; your relative horizontal cursor position can immediately be calculated from that. (Although I am not sure why you don't do the same for `y`.) It helps to visualize your calculations as not only a *zoom* but as a *translation* as well.

Comment: That is just for separating the work in 4 equal parts so i can use multiple threads(if I have 600 pixels the first thread does the pixels 0 to 150 and so on), I have the cursor x and y because when the user scrolls a function is called. My problem is just how to change the point where the zoom happens from the centre of the fractal to whatever point the cursor is at.

Comment: Can you debug or output in another way what the actual values of `(mv_x,mv_y)` are that are used in `julia_thread`? For zoom_factor 1 or 2 it should work as intended, for all other it should not work at all, returning a unicolor square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **very bad** idea to do indiscriminate integer divisions:

```
2 / zoom_factor
```

will return 0 if `zoom_factor` is larger than 2. Replace `2` by `2.0` to force floating point division, this should be sufficient to repair the code.

---

If I interpret this correctly, you want that the screen window represents a square in the coordinate or fractal plane with the width and height `4.0/zoom_factor` around the point `(mv_x, mv_y)`.

`mv` is situated at `WIN_SIZE/2`, so that

```
coord = mv + ( 4*value/WIN_SIZE - 2 )/zoom_factor
```

which can be implemented exactly as this

```
return mv + ( (4.0*value)/WIN_SIZE - 2.0 )/zoom_factor;
```

and with the factor `4.0` the denominator gets type double and division is carried out in double.

---

### Slow derivation

What the function `range_change` wants to achieve is a linear change of coordinates

```
coord = A*screen + B
```

where `screen` is the input screen coordinate and `coord` is the coordinate in the Cartesian plane playing host for the Julia fractal. The endpoint mapping is

```
screen=0         --> coord = center - 2.0/zoom
screen=WIN_SIZE  --> coord = center + 2.0/zoom
```

From the first we read `B=center - 2.0/zoom` and from the second formula

```
A*WIN_SIZE + center - 2.0/zoom = center + 2.0/zoom
A*WIN_SIZE                     =          4.0/zoom
A = 4.0/(zoom*WIN_SIZE)
```

which gives the transformation formula

```
coord = (4.0*value)/(zoom*WIN_SIZE) + center - 2.0/zoom
      = ( (4.0*value)/WIN_SIZE - 2.0 )/zoom + center
```

Comment: What fractal dimension (this is a standard mathematical notion, also called Hausdorff dimension)? But you are right, the previous version would have given real coordinates from `mv-0.5/zoom_factor` to `mv-0.5/zoom_factor`, which contradicts the stated pixel size. Now from `mv-(0.5*WIN_SIZE)/zoom_factor` to `mv+(0.5*WIN_SIZE)/zoom_factor`.

Comment: Where do you find your accusations? A fractal is a point set in some vector space with the property of self-similarity under certain transformations. What is called Julia or Mandelbrot set in computer graphics is some kind of colored distance map to these fractal sets. The squares  [-2,2]×[-2,2] or [-2.5,1.5]×[-2,2] are viewports into these color maps, the first usually for the full Julia, the second for the full Mandelbrot set.